# SQL error when inserting new record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm encountering a very strange when I insert a new record into a table in my SQL SErver DB instance.  I have the following simple query:

```
INSERT myTable (SerialNumber, PartNumber, IP, QA) VALUES ('123456789012', '1234567','192.168.1.1','1')
```

And the table I'm trying to modify:

```
SerialNumber - varchar(64) - Not_Null

PartNumber - varchar(64) - Null

IP- varchar(64) - Null

Col_1   - varchar(64)  - Null

Col_2   - bit - Null

Col_3   - bit - Null

QA  - bit - Null
```

Now when I run this query in SQL Server Management Studio I get the following error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

Nowhere in my table do I have a column with a datetime type, so I do not why I'm getting this error.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any triggers on that table?

Comment: I notice question is answered - what was the problem - was it a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce with the following script on sql server 2005

```
declare @myTable table
(
    SerialNumber varchar(64) Not Null,
    PartNumber  varchar(64)  Null,
    IP varchar(64)  Null,
    Col_1  varchar(64)  Null,
    Col_2  bit  Null,
    Col_3  bit  Null,
    QA  bit  Null
)

INSERT @myTable (SerialNumber, PartNumber, IP, QA) VALUES ('123456789012', '1234567','192.168.1.1','1')
select * from @myTable
```

It worked as expected ... Can you double check to be sure that you don't have a trigger on your table?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried that table definition and query on SQL Server Express 2005 and works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

this insert looks fine, with no datetime data types in sight.  Is there a trigger on the table that might insert a datetime??  try this to see if there is any trigger:

```
sp_helptrigger myTable
```